# Why does BibTeX ignores the last one-line entry?

Tags: bibtex

I'm working on tests for a BibTeX parser in Lua which is aimed at the original BibTeX's syntax and the following case confuses me. The first three cites are printed out as expected but the last is undefined. BibTeX (TeX Live 2023) gives a warning `I didn't find a database entry for "ITEM-4"`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@misc{ITEM-1, author = "Doe"} @misc{ITEM-2, author = "Doe"}
@misc{ITEM-3, author = "Doe"} @misc{ITEM-4, author = "Doe"}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\cite{ITEM-1, ITEM-2, ITEM-3, ITEM-4}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You need a carriage return after the last line.

Comment: @AlanMunn the bib file does end with a newline (two newlines makes bibtex happy)  bibtex bug?

Comment: if `@misc{ITEM-4, author = "Doe"}` starts a line the file can end at `}` if it is on the same line as the previous entry it needs two end of line before the file end

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I didn't say it didn't. :)

Comment: Always put `@` on a new line and you'll live happy. I've *never* seen two BibTeX entries on the same line. I agree that this is a bug in BibTeX, though.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It's very likely to be a bug. Another observation is that ITEM-4 is accepted if there is a line break in the middle (`@misc{ITEM-4,\nauthor = "Doe"}`).

Comment: @ZepingLee That's normal. Entries commonly put a line break at the end of the key line and after each field. That is, assuming your `\n` isn't literal but is an actual line break.